# How to programmatically change views in TabBarViewController?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have two instances where I want to re-direct the user to the main view of a TabBarViewController.  I've tried BringSubViewToFront(), but that does nothing... I basically want to activate the first tab (home tab?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your TabViewController already has all the ViewControllers created for each tab, simply changing the `SelectedIndex` property in the tabbar does what you're looking for:

> myTabBarController.SelectedIndex = 2;

Will send you to the third tab (array is zero-based).