# Is it possible to change the actual ViewController on a UITabBarController in Monotouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Monotouch App, on AppDelegate the RootViewController is a TabBarController, this TabBarController have 5 ViewControllers, lets say view1 to view5, I use

```
tabBarController.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

for select which viewController will load when the app starts it works and the default tabBar is view3, now I need to show another viewController, lets say from view1 change to view5 with code, its possible? there's a way to emulate the clic on one of the buttons of my TabBar, that will work too...

UPDATE:

I tried:

```
view1.TabBarController.ViewControllers[4].PresentViewController(view5, true, delegate{});
```

And it works, but the view5 is presented over the TabBar, also I try this:

```
view1.TabBarController.TabBar.Items[4]. //I don't know which method could invoke the click
```

Where I select the item of the tabbar I want to click

I think the solution is close to this, the problem is that always the view5 shows over the TabBar and block it...

SOLVED:

```
view1.TabBarController.SelectedIndex = 2; //where the number is the view zero-based
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what you want?  You can call this from any click handler.

```
AppDelegate.Current.NavController.PushViewController(new View5(), true);
```

In my AppDelegate class I have:

```
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    public static AppDelegate Current { get; private set; }
    public UINavigationController NavController { get; private set; }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Current = this;
        NavController = new UINavigationController();
        ...
    }
}
```

or do you want to just switch tabs: [How to programmatically change views in TabBarViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4729300/353147)

Comment: Thanks Chuck, i feel so dumb... view1.TabBarController.SelectedIndex = 4; was my first attempt, but the Iphone simulator throw a error and i think that "SelectedIndex" was for use only when created the TabBarController. Actually the error was throw by something else on the same action, i erase all.. only leave that line and it works.

Comment: Your welcome - which worked for you?  (also check the answer as correct with the checkmark so others don't feel they need to answer it).