# Keep tab bar but change view controller for specific tab bar item

Tags: xamarin, uitabbarcontroller

Struggling to try change the View Controller been shown in one of my Tab items.

I have three tab items and can display the view controller for each one without issue.

On the third view controller I trigger a QR Scanning camera on a button press (ViewController #1) which once it scans the QR Code then closes and forwards the user to a view controller (ViewController #2) using a PresentViewController call.

Thing is I need this 2nd view controller presented in place of the original #1 such that the Tab items are still presented at the bottom. Is this at all possible?

The code I am currently using on ViewController #1 to show the 2nd VC is as follows and works, its just showing the VC on top of the Tab Bar where as I need it to actually replace View Controller #1

```
UIStoryboard board = UIStoryboard.FromName ("Main", null);
VC_DisplayScanResult ctrl = (VC_DisplayScanResult)board.InstantiateViewController ("sbid_vcscanresult");

TabBarMain rootTabBar = (TabBarMain)this.ParentViewController;
rootTabBar.PresentViewController(ctrl, true, null);
```

I added the solution described at [Is it possible to change the actual ViewController on a UITabBarController in Monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824821/is-it-possible-to-change-the-actual-viewcontroller-on-a-uitabbarcontroller-in-mo) by adding the AppDelegate related code etc. No errors occur but neither does the View Controller change.

What I am trying to achieve is as follows:

1. When Tab3 is touched it displays ViewController 1
2. On View Controller 1 - Button pressed, camera opens, QR Code scanned, the camera closes and View Controller 2 is displayed. Tab 3 still selected and showing.

With the above code used I have something similair but View Controller 2 is shown but its been presented like a Modal and is full screen, no Tab controls displayed.

[image: Workflow]

I will eventually want to open a 3rd Viewcontroller from the 2nd.

I want to avoid Segues for this workflow.

Comment: Why aren't you exchanging the controllers? So if someone taps your third tab your second controller will be presented, that will present your first controller through `PresentViewController(new VC1(), true, null);` on `ViewDidLoad`.

Comment: Not quite I understand or if I have explained correctly. I will update my question with screen shots and better explanation of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm not wanting to change the ViewController to #2 on Tab tap but on a button tap on the first view controller.

Comment: Ok, I just realised that I had to embed the view controllers been displayed on third tab in a NavigationController and simply hide it.